# Missing Config.toml and Cloud.toml in Ballerina templates pushed to Ballerina Central

Tags: configuration, ballerina

I have created a Ballerina template with the following configurations in the `Ballerina.toml` file.

```
[package]
org = "wso2ohtest"
name = "fhir.api"
version = "0.1.4"
authors=["WSO2"]
distribution = "2201.1.2"
template = true

[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true
```

Inside this Ballerina template project, it includes the `Config.toml` and `Cloud.toml` files.

I packed the project with the `bal pack` command and pushed it to Ballerina Central with the `bal push` command. However, when I try to pull the pushed template project from Ballerina Central using
`bal new new-fhir-api -t <template_name:version>`, the  aforementioned `.toml` files are missing.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 2201.2.0 onwards files and directories that need to be packed inside the bala can be specified using the field `include` under the `package` table in the `Ballerina.toml` file.

```
[package]
# removed for brevity
include=["Cloud.toml", "Config.toml"]
```

Note that you have to provide the path from the root of the package.

From Update 3 onwards, it is also possible to specify wildcard patterns similar to `.gitignore`  patterns.

As an example,

```
[package]
# removed for brevity
include=["*.toml"]
```

This will pack all the files that has the extention `.toml` in the bala.

Please refer the documentation [include-field](https://ballerina.io/learn/package-references/#the-include-field)